# Ember relationships and mongo relationships

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ember.js

I'm trying to figure out the best approach to my Ember App.

I'm working with two models: events and bookings, and in my database, I structured they totally separate and independent from each other.

Schemas:

Events:

```
attributes:
  date        : Date
  description : String
  hiw         : Object
  hour        : Date
  meeting     : String
  men         : Number
  name        : String
  women       : Number

  createdAt   : Date
  updatedAt   : Date

  isActive    :
    type    : Boolean
    default : false

type:
  type    : String
  default : 'event'
```

Bookings:

```
attributes:
  email         : String
  idiom         : String
  name          : String
  obs           : String
  participants  : Number
  phone         : String
  sex           : String
  vip           : String

  createdAt    : Date
  updatedAt    : Date

  isActive     :
    type    : Boolean
    default : false

type:
  type    : String
  default : 'booking'
```

As I'm learning Ember, I discovered that ember has relationships (belongsTo and hasMany), and I would ask if I should restructure schemas to deal with Ember, or if I should make them independent as i'm doing.

The tendency of bookings is be progressively more complex over time..

The Ember relationships is for this kind of stuff, or is to simple things like, comments in posts.. etc. etc..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask yourself if they depend on each other, if answer is yes than you should use relationships both in Ember.js and node.js. You probably use `mongoose` so it's easy to create relationships on server side.